# Do you always have to use jade in Node js to display html pages

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I have been making little web apps this summer and new to web in general and i have been using the node.js express framework. I use jade for templating, and it really has been an inconvenience using it urghhh, is it possible i could just send the angular html page instead of converting it to jade ?

For example:

An app that gets data from an api, then on the client side uses angular to get this data and display it on the webpage `index.html` instead of using jade to display this data.

in `pseudo` code

**app.js** `server side`

```
var data = require("./people.json");

app.get('/getall', function(req, res){

    res.send(data)

});
```

**app.js** `client side`

```
  $http({method: 'GET', url: '/getall'}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.myData = data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    });
```

This is what i normally do:

**index.jade**

```
div(ng-repeat='person in myData')
    span  {{person.name}}
```

This is what i want to be able to do:

**index.html:**

```
<div ng-repeat = 'person in myData' > 
<span> {{person.name}}</span>
</div>
```

I understand jade is for templating and angular is an mvc, its just really annoying that i use angular and have to convert it to jade !

Hope i have explained myself enough !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you always have to use jade in Node js to display html pages

No, you can use whatever you want.

Node.js doesn't dictate anything, it's just an application framework.  [Express doesn't dictate either](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.engine), and in fact uses a [common API for templating engines](https://github.com/visionmedia/consolidate.js?_ga=1.42444581.1066942740.1409868988).

You also don't even need to use a template engine, and it sounds to me like what you want is to just serve static HTML files.  [Use the `static` middleware](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#middleware.builtin) if that's what you want.

**Code Example** (untested, but start with this):

```
var data = require('./people.json');
app.get('/getall', function (req, res) {
    res.send(data)
});

app.use(express.static('static')); // Use a directory called "static" for your static files
```

If you have a file in your project called `static/something.html`, you will now be able to access it at http://example.com/something.html or whatever your hostname is.

Comment: The good news is that there are a gajillion node.js templating options.  The bad news is that there are a gajillion node.js templating options.  :-)

Comment: @Brad , Thanks for your answer, it was really informative and yes all i want to do is serve a static html page ! , but in my above example, how do i serve this static page ?

Comment: @Pizzy213codes I linked you to the instructions.  `app.use(express.static('static-file-path/'))`

Comment: @Brad, not sure how that works tbh, do put `app.use(express.static('static-file-path/'))` in the app.get callback method ? im lost, hope i get the noob pass :)